# How to get optional parameters from a url and use them to parse objects from a model?

Tags: python, django

For example, from the url: [https://localhost:8000/parameters=param1&param2&param3](http://localhost:8000)

How can I parse out the parameters as a list and pass it into a class-based view?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('parameters=...', MyListView.as_view()),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class MyListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = MyObject.objects.all() # Use the parameters to filter out objects
    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer
```

**models.py**

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=120)


# Each object can have an unlimited number of parameters
class ObjectParameters(models.Model):
    my_object = models.ForeignKey(MyObject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    param = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

I would like to query a list of objects that contain all given parameters. Also, is this a logical structure for my models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, you don't need to do anything to handle the [**query parameters**--(Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in the `path(...)` function.

So change your urls.py as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('some/path/', MyListView.as_view()),
]
```

Then, in your view, override the **`get_queryset(...)`** method as

```
class MyListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyObject.objects.all()
        param = self.request.query_params.get("parameter_name")
        if param:
            queryset = queryset.filter(some_model_field=param)
        return queryset
```

So, now, DRF view expect query parameter in the form,

```
https://localhost:8000/some/path/?parameter_name=foo&parameter_name=bar
```

---

I would highly recommend using the matured [**`django-filter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package for this